# Regarding basic html, borders of the div tag

Tags: html, css

I am learning html and i cant understand why when i have two lines inside one div the second line doesn't fall within the borders of the div.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="testingsite.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div><header><h3>Line 1</h3>
         <br><h5>Line 2</h5></header></div>

</body>
```

My css isn't showing in a code block properly so i put a jsfiddle link below.

Thanks for any help.
https://jsfiddle.net/xLjsmrfc/

Comment: You have fixed width of header.  `height: 75px;` remove it. It will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this one:

add `height :auto;`

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid blue;

}

header {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    width: 100%;



}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xLjsmrfc/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a height property set in the CSS for the header tag.

`height: 75px;`

This restricts the height of the `<header>`, and thus the border. Remove the height property and things will correct.

Answer (score 1):

Dear you are writing the code right but there is a small flaw in Css.

Both lines are falling within the Div just height of Div is Creating dilemma for you.

I've two methods for you :

----------1. **Altering Your own code**----------

```
  body {
      background-color: white;
      border: 5px solid blue;

  }

  header {
      text-align: center;
      height: 155px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid blue;
      width: 100%;   
  }
```

----------2. **Second My Way :**----------

```
<style>
   body {
         background-color: white;
         border: 5px solid blue;
        }

  #myid{
        text-align: center;
        height: 155px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 5px solid blue;
        width: 100%;   
       }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myid">
      <header>
           <h3>Line 1</h3><br>
           <h5>Line 2</h5>
      </header>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really with the styling you've done. 
Change the div height to something like greater than the current `75px`

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    height: 105px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    width: 100%;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using `heading tag` then those tags are taking their own padding and margin by which they are out of your border as you have given height to container so use heading tag according to  your need.

Answer (score 0):

Header tags ( `h1...h5` ) have some default margins.

You can add the `margin:0px` for that and it will work fine.